# Recursive file copy

Tags: python, spyder

I would like to recursively add files to a directory with a set naming scheme.

```
import os
def all_files(directory):
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for f in files:
        yield os.path.join(path, f)


xlsm_files = [f for f in all_files('H:\Practice')
           if f.endswith('.xlsm')]
print(xlsm_files)

from shutil import copyfile               
for i in (xlsm_files):
    copyfile(i,'H:/Practice/Crawler Test/i.xlsm')
```

For this example, I have two files named: name1.xlsm and name2.xlsm.

Currently I can copy with xlsm_files[1] and xlsm_files[2] with individually adding. However, I would like to eventually have 100s of files and writing individually would take forever, not to mention as the list grows, I may not be able to keep up.

**bonus points if I can learn to take it one step further to read H:/Practice/Crawler Test/ , see the files in there, and only have the crawler find files that aren't currently in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the first question, still working on bonus

```
import fnmatch
import os
import shutil
rootPath = 'H:\\Practice\\'
destDir = 'C:\Users\******\Downloads\Crawler Test'
matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootPath):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.xlsm'):
      matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
      a = (os.path.join(root, filename))
      print(a)
      shutil.copy2(a, destDir)
```